# website downloading Amazon Polly's voice as mp3 file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, text-to-speech, amazon-polly

I'm a beginner in coding. I would like to make a simple website using Amazon Polly.

1. a web site with a text box
2. you write a text in the text box and click a button "Read"
3. you can download a mp3 file which is made by Amazon Polly

I'm an English teacher in Japan, so I would like my students to use this website to improve their English pronunciation.

I have realized 1 and 2, but not 3. I can't find the way to download AudioStream as a mp3 file.
I use flask, Amazon Polly and AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

This is application.py

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from flask import Flask, jsonify, Response, render_template, request, send_file
import os
import sys

from boto3 import Session
from botocore.exceptions import BotoCoreError, ClientError

# Mapping the output format used in the client to the content type for the
# response
AUDIO_FORMATS = {"ogg_vorbis": "audio/ogg",
                 "mp3": "audio/mpeg",
                 "pcm": "audio/wave; codecs=1"}

# Create a client using the credentials and region defined in the adminuser
# section of the AWS credentials and configuration files
session = Session(aws_access_key_id='???', aws_secret_access_key='???', region_name='us-east-1')
polly = session.client("polly")

# Create a flask app
application = Flask(__name__)


# Simple exception class
class InvalidUsage(Exception):
    status_code = 400

    def __init__(self, message, status_code=None, payload=None):
        Exception.__init__(self)
        self.message = message
        if status_code is not None:
            self.status_code = status_code
        self.payload = payload

    def to_dict(self):
        rv = dict(self.payload or ())
        rv['message'] = self.message
        return rv


# Register error handler
@application.errorhandler(InvalidUsage)
def handle_invalid_usage(error):
    response = jsonify(error.to_dict())
    response.status_code = error.status_code
    return response


@application.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@application.route('/read', methods=['GET'])
def read():
    """Handles routing for reading text (speech synthesis)"""
    # Get the parameters from the query string
    try:
        outputFormat = request.args.get('outputFormat')
        text = request.args.get('text')
        voiceId = request.args.get('voiceId')
    except TypeError:
        raise InvalidUsage("Wrong parameters", status_code=400)

    # Validate the parameters, set error flag in case of unexpected
    # values
    if len(text) == 0 or len(voiceId) == 0 or \
            outputFormat not in AUDIO_FORMATS:
        raise InvalidUsage("Wrong parameters", status_code=400)
    else:
        try:
            # Request speech synthesis
            response = polly.synthesize_speech(Text='<speak><amazon:domain name="conversational"><prosody rate="slow">' + text + '</prosody></amazon:domain></speak>',
                                               VoiceId=voiceId, Engine='neural', TextType='ssml',
                                               OutputFormat=outputFormat)
        except (BotoCoreError, ClientError) as err:
            # The service returned an error
            raise InvalidUsage(str(err), status_code=500)

        return send_file(response.get("AudioStream"),
                         AUDIO_FORMATS[outputFormat])


# Define and parse the command line arguments
cli = ArgumentParser(description='Example Flask Application')
cli.add_argument(
    "-p", "--port", type=int, metavar="PORT", dest="port", default=8000)
cli.add_argument(
    "--host", type=str, metavar="HOST", dest="host", default="localhost")
arguments = cli.parse_args()


# If the module is invoked directly, initialize the application
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Configure and run flask app
    application.secret_key = os.urandom(24)
    application.debug = True
    application.run(arguments.host, arguments.port)
```

This is index.html

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Text-to-Speech Example Application</title>
    <script>
        /*
         * This sample code requires a web browser with support for both the
         * HTML5 and ECMAScript 5 standards; the following is a non-comprehensive
         * list of compliant browsers and their minimum version:
         *
         * - Chrome 23.0+
         * - Firefox 21.0+
         * - Internet Explorer 9.0+
         * - Edge 12.0+
         * - Opera 15.0+
         * - Safari 6.1+
         * - Android (stock web browser) 4.4+
         * - Chrome for Android 51.0+
         * - Firefox for Android 48.0+
         * - Opera Mobile 37.0+
         * - iOS (Safari Mobile and Chrome) 3.2+
         * - Internet Explorer Mobile 10.0+
         * - Blackberry Browser 10.0+
         */

        // Mapping of the OutputFormat parameter of the SynthesizeSpeech API
        // and the audio format strings understood by the browser
        var AUDIO_FORMATS = {
            'ogg_vorbis': 'audio/ogg',
            'mp3': 'audio/mpeg',
            'pcm': 'audio/wave; codecs=1'
        };

        /**
         * Handles fetching JSON over HTTP
         */
        function fetchJSON(method, url, onSuccess, onError) {
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open(method, url, true);
            request.onload = function () {
                // If loading is complete
                if (request.readyState === 4) {
                    // if the request was successful
                    if (request.status === 200) {
                        var data;

                        // Parse the JSON in the response
                        try {
                            data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                        } catch (error) {
                            onError(request.status, error.toString());
                        }

                        onSuccess(data);
                    } else {
                        onError(request.status, request.responseText)
                    }
                }
            };

            request.send();
        }

        /**
         * Returns a list of audio formats supported by the browser
         */
        function getSupportedAudioFormats(player) {
            return Object.keys(AUDIO_FORMATS)
                .filter(function (format) {
                    var supported = player.canPlayType(AUDIO_FORMATS[format]);
                    return supported === 'probably' || supported === 'maybe';
                });
        }

        // Initialize the application when the DOM is loaded and ready to be
        // manipulated
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            var input = document.getElementById('input'),
                voiceMenu = document.getElementById('voice'),
                text = document.getElementById('text'),
                player = document.getElementById('player'),
                submit = document.getElementById('submit'),
                supportedFormats = getSupportedAudioFormats(player);

            // Display a message and don't allow submitting the form if the
            // browser doesn't support any of the available audio formats
            if (supportedFormats.length === 0) {
                submit.disabled = true;
                alert('The web browser in use does not support any of the' +
                      ' available audio formats. Please try with a different' +
                      ' one.');
            }

            // Play the audio stream when the form is submitted successfully
            input.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
                // Validate the fields in the form, display a message if
                // unexpected values are encountered
                if (text.value.length === 0) {
                    alert('Please fill in all the fields.');
                } else {
                    var selectedVoice = voiceMenu
                                            .options[voiceMenu.selectedIndex]
                                            .value;

                    // Point the player to the streaming server
                    player.src = '/read?voiceId=' +
                        encodeURIComponent(selectedVoice) +
                        '&text=' + encodeURIComponent(text.value) +
                        '&outputFormat=' + supportedFormats[0];
                    player.play();
                }

                // Stop the form from submitting,
                // Submitting the form is allowed only if the browser doesn't
                // support Javascript to ensure functionality in such a case
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });

    </script>
    <style>
        #input {
            min-width: 100px;
            max-width: 600px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 50px;
        }

        #input div {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }

        #text {
            width: 100%;
            height: 200px;
            display: block;
        }

        #submit {
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="input" method="GET" action="/read">
        <div>
            <label for="voice">Select a voice:</label>
            <select id="voice" name="voiceId">
                <option value="Joanna">Joanna</option>
                <option value="Matthew">Matthew</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="text">Text to read:</label>
            <textarea id="text" maxlength="1000" minlength="1" name="text"
                    placeholder="Type some text here..."></textarea>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Read" id="submit" />
    </form>
    <audio id="player"></audio>
</body>

</html>
```

I think I should add a javascript code like this. However, I don't know what to put in "var content" and I don't know where to put this javascript code in index.html.

```
<body>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        function handleDownload() {
            var content = ??????;
            var blob = new Blob([ content ], { "type" : "audio/mp3" });                
            document.getElementById("download").href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);  
        }
    </script>
    <a id="download" href="#" download="test.mp3" onclick="handleDownload()">downloadMP3</a>
</body>
```

Could you give me any information or suggestion?

Thank you in advance.

Sincerely, Kazu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, you can call [`start_speech_synthesis_task()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/polly.html#Polly.Client.start_speech_synthesis_task):

> This operation requires all the standard information needed for speech synthesis, plus **the name of an Amazon S3 bucket for the service to store the output of the synthesis task** and two optional parameters (OutputS3KeyPrefix and SnsTopicArn). Once the synthesis task is created, this operation will return a SpeechSynthesisTask object, which will include an identifier of this task as well as the current status.

Therefore, you can **request Amazon Polly to store the output of the speech to an mp3 file in Amazon S3**. The application can then provide a URL to the mp3 file. This could either be a public file with a random name, or the application could generate a **pre-signed URL** that grants temporary access to the mp3 file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful answer, John. I didn't know "start_speech_synthesis_task". I'll try to use this operation and if it does't work, I'll ask again. Thank you so much!!